# How to access and manipulate views inside a ListView item?

Tags: android, listview

I've made s simple checklist application which displays a listview with checkboxes and text that changes when the item is checked. I wanted to save the state of the items (whether they're checked or not) and I accomplished that but now I'm at a loss as to how to access the checkbox inside each checked item to check it when the listview loads. I can not use onlistitemclick listener because the list is not being clicked. It just loads and is supposed to show which items are already clicked when it does. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Define your own adapter and implement CheckBoxes using icons. Android does not support onClickListener for ListView's items containing controls.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Because I have already dealt with the checkboxes in onClickListener - they become ticked when I click on the list item - but they won't get a green tick sign when I restore the item's checked state from my shared preferences. The latter is what I wish to achieve. :)